# Can I edit package documentation on pub.dev after publishing?

Tags: flutter, dart, package, pub.dev

I wrote a pub package, but since the README is in markdown and there is no markdown preview in **Android Studio**, the documentation I wrote turned out bad. I used
https://stackedit.io/app# to see how it looks, and there it looks fine, but after publishing it, the one on [pub.dev](https://pub.dev) doesn't look the same as the one from the website. Is there a way to edit a **README** **without** publishing a new package version?

Comment: did you find a way?

Comment: nope, you have to make a new version...